# Select taking long time when data is getting deleted

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

We have a process which delete data from SQL database everyday at a scheduled time. Now when delete operation is going on the 'Select' queries go very slow. Any idea what could be the reason?

One thing here, we are using cascade delete for deleting data and data gets delete from around 150+ tables.

Comment: Well, maybe your system is busy....? Only way out of that is a hardware upgrade: fast SSD instead of slow HD, more RAM, bigger CPU.

Comment: You database maybe fragmented.  Compress the database.

Comment: It is a well known problem, DELETE operations of MS SQL for more or less big tables are catastrophically slow (unlike Oracle, for instance). All the ways to solve this problem require deep data analysis. Sometimes table partitioning can help, sometimes the simplest way is tables recreation and copying.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the transaction isolation level.

You are not saying what type of DB you are using but I guess it supports different types of isolation. Probably the default one is that one query can't read uncommitted data so the select waits for the first transaction to finish.

For example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) is the list of Isolations levels for SQL Server

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's a SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

> Now when delete operation is going on the 'Select' queries go very slow. Any idea what could be the reason?

Troubleshoot based on WaitTypes...

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_requests where session_id='spid of select '
```

You will be able to see why your select is slow,like ..is it blocked